# how can animate infinite this box when click "button"?

Tags: jquery, animation

How can I make this animation run forever after clicking the button?

```
$("button").click(function(){
    var a=$("#an");
    a.animate({width:200,opacity:0.5},"slow");
    a.animate({height:200,opacity:0.5},"slow");
    a.animate({width:100,opacity:0.8},"slow");
    a.animate({height:100,opacity:0.8},"slow");
})
```

Comment: Describe your problem more, Its not clear. `:P`

Comment: Hi! welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is not clear. Please spend more time explaining the problem.

Comment: i want repeat the animation when  click the button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" id="button" value="start" />

<div id="an" style="width:100px; height:100px;background-color:red">

<script>
$("#button").click(function(){

    var a = $("#an");
    if ($(this).val() == 'start') {
        $(this).val("stop");
        var v = setInterval(function(){animate(a)},1000);
    }

})

function animate(a) {
    a.animate({width:200,opacity:0.5},"slow");
    a.animate({height:200,opacity:0.5},"slow");
    a.animate({width:100,opacity:0.8},"slow");
    a.animate({height:100,opacity:0.8},"slow");
}

</script>
```

Comment: Posts solemnly consisting of *"Try this `<code block>`"* are rarely good answers. A good answers tries to explain the problem and solution, to educated the reader.

Comment: It's working fine on my side, have a look at this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/factorde7/vAqyu/1/

Comment: hmm welcome, would you like to mark my answer as "Accepted" now? :)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's best to use CSS's animation to get this to work.  I coded it here with the -webkit prefix-

http://jsfiddle.net/6GX2E/

And just triggered with this jQuery:

```
$("button").click(function(){
     $("#an").removeClass('noAnimate').addClass('animate');
});
```

Comment: thanks...good job ! but i have work to ie ...so it is possible on jquery only :)